# Free() call hangs the thread forever

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, free, embedded-linux

Thread1 -
Creates (malloc) and Adds a message to the message queue.

Thread2 -
Receives the message from the message queue, and Processes the message and frees it

But when freeing the message the Thread2 hangs forever.

Note- 
Application is multi threaded embedded linux application.

No possibility of double free.

Does not happen always, very occasionally.

Question 
1. Can call to free be a blocking call? or when it can happen?
2.Has anyone faced similar issue, please point us to the possible root cause of the problem.

Comment: Well either getmessage() / putmessage() is nonreentrant, or malloc() / free() is nonreentrant.

Comment: After having invoked undefined behaviour anything could happen.

Comment: I always go for what ever does the allocation, does the deallocation myself. Anything else makes me nervous.

Comment: @alk - What UB are you seeing in the OP's description?

Comment: @phonetagger: I actually do not see it, but I do smell it, smell the breaks/tires from the thread's fullstop in `free()`. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that the memory pool for both threads is the same?  Perhaps collect used pointers in thread 2, and every so often (maybe after you collect 1024 of 'em or whatever), send the "used" array of pointers back to thread 1 via a separate message, and thread 1 can either free the allocations or re-use them.

Comment: @wildplasser you mean malloc and free should be secured by mutex/synchronization method even if the program is compiled with -D_REENTRANT, and linked with -lpthread ?

Comment: @phonetagger Both threads use the same memory space of memory i.e heap.

Comment: The only obvious way this could go wrong is if non-multithread version of the standard library was linked in, so rendering malloc and free thread-unsafe.  mallocing a struct, queueing the pointer to another thread and then freeing there is certainly not unusual.  If there is just one global heap, signaling/queuing the pointers back to the thread that malloced them is either a waste of time/CPU, or (a waste of time/CPU and also not sensibly possible because the originator thread is normally stuck on a blocking call).  I just assume that the queue is thread-safe?

Comment: A cheap way to find out: 0) preallocate a lot of messages before starting the second thread and put them into a dummy queue (which acts as a freelist) 1) instead of malloc() / free(), obtain objects from this queue, and after use put them back into this queue.

Comment: @wildplasser  Preallocation would be difficult in our case due to limited memory,We cannot predict the no of message needed :(. Does malloc and free should be protected with mutex, though the application is linked with lpthread? We had removed the mutex for malloc & free, thinking its unnecessary!!?

Comment: You really think that without preallocation memory would be unlimited?

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks. No, not ... there might be other threads which will require memory... We cannot lockup huge memory for this thread alone Also since that much might not be required all the time for this thread. ( Hence we allocate the memory for the message from heap on need basis). Assume a design change is not possible currently.

Comment: BTW: does the program have signal handlers, too?

Comment: You mention your system has other threads than these two. Do you have the ability to observe the stack backtrace of all the running threads when the system is in the locked up state? Perhaps your thread 2 that is doing the `free()` is a victim of some other errant thread.

Comment: @wildplasser we do have signal handlers

Comment: What do the signal handlers _do_, do they manipulate the queues, or do they call printf() or fprintf() to log events?